# Utilizing local variables of a function and setTimeout

Tags: javascript, css, image, settimeout, opacity

I have hit a snag in a website I am building. I have a function which adds a specific class to different ids. The end result is to have images fade out one at a time on the home page. I used the local variable a so that I can easily code the different id's without having to write 3 separate functions. However I am having trouble using setTimeout. I cannot seem to get setTimeout to work at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The classes get added to the ids with no problem, I am just having trouble with the setTimeout function. I've used multiple methods I've seen on here but I don't really understand them. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```js
window.onload;

var fetchOne =document.getElementById('picOne');
console.log(fetchOne);

var fetchTwo =document.getElementById('picTwo');
var fetchThree =document.getElementById('picThree');

function AttachClass (a){
    
    a.className ='opacity';
    
}

setTimeout(AttachClass.bind(null,a),8000);

AttachClass (fetchOne);

AttachClass (fetchTwo);

AttachClass (fetchThree);
```

```css
#picOne{
    
    opacity: 1;
    
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out
    
    
}

#picOne.opacity{
    opacity: 0;
    
    
    
}

#picTwo{
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out
    
    
}

#picTwo.opacity{
    opacity: 0;
    
}

#picThree{
   opacity: 1;
    z-index: -2;
    

    transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out
}

#picThree.opacity{
    opacity: 0;
   
    
}
```

```html
<div class="landscape_pics">
        
        <img id="picOne" src="media/Photographs/BK3U8791.JPG">
        <img id="picTwo" src="media/Photographs/2014Feb%20-%20Vacation%20-%20Sao%20Paulo%20-%200071a.jpg">
        <img id="picThree" src="media/Photographs/2014Aug06%20-%20Stadium%20-%20001.JPG">
        
        
    </div>
```

Comment: `The classes get added to the ids with no problem` - Well this is not true since `ReferenceError: a is not defined` setting the `className` will not work. Do you know your setting an `undefined` param for `AttachClass` function?

Answer (score 0):

You're only setting up 1 handler for 1 image with that timeout ***and*** `a` is never defined within the code you've pasted so the `setTimeout` won't work.

In order for them to fade out separately you'd need to create one `setTimeout` per image you want faded.

```
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(AttachClass.bind(null, images[i]), 2000);
}
```

Secondly, that `window.onload` seems to be a remnant of something, you can safely remove that.

Thirdly, there's no need to call the function `AttachClass` after you've setup the `setTimeout` since it's now handled by `setTimeout`.

Now you'd just need to stick the images you've queried the DOM for in to an array called `images` and off you'd go.

It'd look something like this

```
var fetchOne = document.getElementById('picOne');
var fetchTwo = document.getElementById('picTwo');
var fetchThree = document.getElementById('picThree');

function AttachClass(a) {
    a.classList.add('opacity'); // IE10+ support only
};

let images = [fetchOne, fetchTwo, fetchThree];

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(AttachClass.bind(null, images[i]), 5000);
}
```

If you'd like to have it further refined, you could stick a class on all images. I chose the class name `pic`, query the DOM for that class name and then set the above timeouts.

```
var images = document.getElementsByClassName('pic');

function AttachClass(a) {
  a.classList.add('opacity'); 
}

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(AttachClass.bind(null, images[i]), 1000);
}
```

[JSBIN here](http://jsbin.com/miqoriyeza/edit?html,js,output) for you to play around with!
Happy hacking!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need something like this:

```js
window.onload = function() {

  AttachClass();

  function AttachClass() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var a = document.querySelector('.pics img:not(.opacity)');
      if (a) {
        a.className = 'opacity';
        AttachClass();
      }
    }, 1200);
  }
}
```

```css
.pics img {
  width: 100px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out
}

img.opacity {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="pics">
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/843090368837042176/Nl-rCb9c_400x400.jpg">
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/843090368837042176/Nl-rCb9c_400x400.jpg">
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/843090368837042176/Nl-rCb9c_400x400.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: interesting take (-;

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help. They helped me find my eventual answer. This is how I ended up solving my snag.

```js
window.onload
var fetchOne =document.getElementById('picOne');
console.log(fetchOne);
var fetchTwo =document.getElementById('picTwo');
var fetchThree =document.getElementById('picThree');



setInterval(function() {
    
    setTimeout(function AttachClass1 (){ fetchOne.className ='opacity';},1000);
    
    setTimeout(function AttachClass2 (){ fetchTwo.className ='opacity';},8000);
        
    setTimeout(function AttachClass3 (){ fetchThree.className ='opacity';},14000);
    
    setTimeout(function RemoveClass2 () { fetchTwo.classList.remove("opacity");},14000)
    
    setTimeout(function RemoveClass1 () { fetchOne.classList.remove("opacity");},18000)
    
    setTimeout(function RemoveClass3 () { fetchThree.classList.remove("opacity");},18000)
    
},24000);
```

The images flip through one at a time just as I wanted. Then they return with the classlist.remove property. I can also control all the intervals as I like. I'm not familiar at all with JQuery yet so some of the answers above confused me a little. A like to stick to mainly just javascript and this is what I am most comfortable with at the moment. Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score -1):

Here you go

```js
 var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.fade');
    var delay = 500;
    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        (function(i){
        setTimeout(function () {
            imgs[i].classList.add('opacity');
        }, delay * (i + 1))
        })(i)
    }
```

```css
.fade {
opacity:.2;
transition: 1s all ease-in-out;
}

.fade.opacity {
opacity:1
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/people/" alt="" class="fade" id="i1">
</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/food/" alt="" class="fade" id="i2">
</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/sports/" alt="" class="fade" id="i3">
</div>
```